# How can i find a WpfRow and WpfCell in a WpfTable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I'm making Coded UI Tests with Visual Studio 2012/2013 for a WPF-application of my company.
Because the development is still in a flux, i want to create test fragments which are generic (with parameters) and can be reused.
Now i have a special case.
I have a mask with a WpfTable (looks like a grid) on it, which contains - per example - a list of all users.
While the test i want to make a DoubleClick on a selected user to open the next mask for editing his/her data.
So i want to program a method for my tests which gets the WpfTable, a ColumnIndex and a UserName as parameters for the search.
So i have programmed this method for stepping through the rows.

```
private void SearchRowAndColumn(WpfTable table)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (n < table.RowCount)
    {
        var row = new WpfRow(table);
        row.SearchProperties.Add(WpfRow.PropertyNames.RowIndex, n.ToString());
        UITestControlCollection foundRows = row.FindMatchingControls();
        if (foundRows.Count > 0)
        {
            row = (WpfRow)foundRows.ToList()[n];
            Keyboard.SendKeys(row, "{Down}", ModifierKeys.None);
            //if (n == 2)
            //{
            //    Mouse.DoubleClick(row, new Point(10, 10));
            //    n = table.RowCount;
            //}
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

As You can see i commented some lines out.
These lines were for a simple test to see, if my idea works and it did.
But now i have the problem, that many rows of my list are out of sight, because i have 74 users, but only 16 are displayed.
When i want to see the other users, i have to scroll down.
So - as You can see in my code - i tried to "scroll" by the Down-key, which works for a little while.
Unfortunately foundRows.Count is always at 18 which matches the number of rows in sight + 2.
So when my index n is at 19 i get an exception because the index is out of range at (WpfRow)foundRows.ToList()[n].
How can i manage to find my row and cell, even if they are out of the visible range?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the control a standard control like `DataGrid` or is it a custom control? I suspect you aren't able to find the rows because they are virtualized by WPF. If the control only displays a small number of items (like 100) it maybe acceptable to turn virtualization off, but this can have perf implication for a large numbers of items.

Comment: We are using in that case the RadGridView from Telerik.
Further i had made a mistake when searching for the row.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the source of the error.
I have made a mistake in the SearchProperties.
It has to be

```
row.SearchProperties.Add(WpfRow.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "Row_" + n);
```

Then it works absolutely fine and it's stepping through the gridrows.